# RHEL raw device (over VMware RDM) performance issues

Tags: vmware-vsphere, performance, rhel5, raw-disk

I'm running RHEL 5.3 over vSphere 4.0U1.
I configured multiple LUNs on my NetApp (Fibre) storage, and added the RDM on two (Linux) VMs, using the Paravirtual SCSI adapter.
One LUN is 100GB in size, successfully mapped to */dev/sdb* on both VMs, 5 more are 500MB in size (mapped to */dev/sd{c-g}*. I also created one partition per device.

I have encountered two issues:
First, writing directly to */dev/sdb1* gives me **~50MB/s**, while any of the */dev/sd{c-g}1* gives me **~9MB/s**.
There is no difference in configuration of the LUNs apart from their size. I am wondering what causes this but this is not my main problem, as I would settle for 9 MB/s.

I created raw devices using udev pretty straightforwardly:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sdb1", RUN+="/bin/raw /dev/raw/raw1 %N"
```

per device

Writing to any of the new raw devices dramatically slows down performance to just over **900KB/s**.

Can anyone point me in a helpful direction?

Thanks in advance,

-- jifa

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you need the Paravirtualized adapter rather than the LSILogic SCSI adapter? Also why do you need to use RDM's here - is this part of some solution that requires direct access to the raw disk?

Comment: I read somewhere it gives better performance.
I tried switching now, and it drops the small RDMs to ~4MB/s and the raw devs to ~250KB/s.

Comment: a bit of research leads me to think udev is not the problem, as the raw devices are created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my performance assessment was wrong to begin with.
I used the great article at http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=481867 that explains I/O performance and figured out writing with small block sizes substantially degrades performance.
Increasing the measurement block size proved normal r/w speeds - problem solved.

Comment: It's all about the IOPS, the drive heads (wherever they are) are a pretty restrictive bottlekneck. Unless you're using SSD's or an array of hundreds of spinning disks then small IO sizes == low bandwidth. Good to see you figured it out on your own.